# How do I stop browser control in .net from flickering

Tags: .net

I have a control where I need to reload browser content very often (like twice a second in some cases). It doesn't matter if it takes long for it to load, but what I don't want is that whole web control is flickering.

I made two web browsers, I always change document of that one which isn't visible, then I wait using a timer until document is loaded and after that I send it to front over the current browser.

This doesn't help, it's still flickering, is there any way how to make it appear smoothly after document is loaded? Meanwhile the previous browser can stay

this whole control is actually kind of chat window, so the background of window is same, however content is growing

Comment: Are you re-rendering all of the content each update? A chat window should theoretically have no 'flicker' if you're simply appending content at the bottom of the container.

Comment: What exactly are you reloading so frequently?  Are you using an update panel with callbacks?

Comment: Yes, I am re-rendering whole html source each time

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 panels inside the control and each web browser is a part of these, instead of changing z-order of webbrowsers, I change the z-order of panels. It stopped flickering. I don't understand why this works, but it works :)